# Object with list in iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have this table:
[image: table]
And this are my object:

```
public class EntityVista {
private String gValoracion;
private boolean modificable;
private Date fechaCosteValido;
private List<Entity> lSia;
```

}

```
public class Entity {
private Date fecha;
private Double coste;
```

}

My **dataTable** works with **primefaces** with label **p:columns** like for and inside other for read lSia. How I can do this with iReport??

THX